# Как правильно задать высоту экрана?

Tags: html, css

При тестовом просмотре сайта на ноуте, выдало вот такую дичь. Подскажите, как правильно рассчитывать высоту экрана, чтобы смотрелось хорошо
сам сайт norum1991.beget.tech
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: media запросы или 
Единицa измерения vh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте vh

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section>
  
</section>
```